# Question regarding finding the partial derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

can someone who is more experienced in partial derivatives explain me this equation? Thank you in advance.

$$f(x,y) = (2x+y)^3\times x$$

1) Calculate the value of $$x=1$$

2) Calculate the value of $$y=2$$

---

Task 1:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 3(2x+y)^2 \color{red}{\times 2x + (2x+y)}$$
Can someone please explain from where do we get $$\color{red}{\times 2x + (2x+y)}$$

---

Task 2:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 3(2x+y)^2 \color{red}{\times x}$$

Can you please explain why the $$\color{red}{\times x}$$ remains in the equation?

Comment: This is unreadable.  Do you mean $\left( 2x+y \right)^{3x}$ or $\left( 2x+y \right)^{3}\times x$?  And what does "calculate the value of $x=1$" mean?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Please read [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960)
and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site.

Comment: @lulu, sorry I tried to use the Math format system but for some reason, it didn't work properly. The second one where the brackets are multiplied by X. Yes x = 1

Comment: We don't even know whether you are taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$ or to $y$, and please edit your MathJax code into the question. If it doesn't work correctly we can help you fix it.

Comment: But what does it mean to calculate the value at $1$?  Do you mean "consider the function $g(y)=f(1,y)=(2+y)^3$" ?  If so, what's the problem?

Comment: @lulu, The first question is to find the derivative with respect to $$X$$ where $$x=1$$ and the second is to find the derivative with respect to $$y$$ where $$y=1$$.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, somehow I managed to edit it properly. The task one is to find the derivative with respect to $$X$$ and task two is with respect to $$Y$$.

Comment: This is by chain rule and the rule of products.

Comment: @WeijunZhou, Thank you for editing the question. I really appreciate that! I thought it is something with relation to the chain rule but shouldn't be just $$3*(2x+y)^2*2x$$

Comment: See my answer. You have a product of two terms and in the first case you need to take derivative with respect to either of them, and keep the other term unchanged. $(uv)'=u'v+uv'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a partial derivative with respect to one variable all work exactly as for the ordinary derivative keeping constant the other variable, for example

$$y=c\implies f(x,c)=g(x)= (2x+c)^3\times x=h(x)\cdot r(x)$$

then

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{dg}{dx}=h'(x)\cdot g(x)+h(x)\cdot g'(x)=3\cdot(2x+c)^2\cdot 2\cdot x+(2x+c)^3\cdot 1=\\=6x(2x+y)^2+(2x+y)^3$$

Comment: Thank you very much! It was extremely helpful!

Comment: You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (2x+y)^3}{\partial (2x+y)}\frac{\partial (2x+y)}{\partial x}x+(2x+y)^3\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=3(2x+y)^2\times 2x+(2x+y)^3,$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial (2x+y)^3}{\partial (2x+y)}\frac{\partial (2x+y)}{\partial y}x=3(2x+y)^2\times x.$$

Comment: I finally got it, thank you very much. Silly me!

Comment: @MarkS. Don't forget to upvote answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am still not able to do that. I need 15 points or more. However, as soon as I got them, I will.

Comment: I see. Keep on studying. Mathematics is fun (and I am a hobbyist).

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y) = x(2x+y)^3$

$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}=3(2x+y)^22x+(2x+y)^3=(2x+y)^2(y+8x)$$
$$\frac {\partial f}{\partial y}=3x(2x+y)^2$$

Comment: you're welcome Mark hope it helped